# List/Array of strings to a single XML attribute in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Is there any `System.XML.Serialization` XML attribute to serialize a collection like `List<string>` or plaint `string[]` array into a single XML attribute?

For example:

```
public class Test
{

   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
   public string Name { get; set; }

   // ???
   public List<string> Values { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

populating it with

```
Test test = new Test 
{
  Name = "foo",
  Values = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" }
}
```

should serialize as XML

```
<Test name="foo" values="a b c" />
```

On a regular basis we have this use case because
"HTML can that too in e.g. the class attribute"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, but why not create a computed property that you use for serialization?

```
public class Test
{

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore] public List<string> Values { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    [XmlAttribute("values")]
    public string SerValues 
    {
        get => string.Join(" ", Values);
        set => Values = value.Split().ToList();
    }
}
```

You should provide some `null`-checks of course.